# powershell json conversion problem correct results only when saving to a variable

Tags: json, powershell, formatting

**Json conversion with between result**

```
> $container=az container list -o json|convertfrom-json
> $container|select name,provisioningstate
```

**Output:**

```
name           provisioningState
----           -----------------
master         Succeeded
pasbackground1 Succeeded
sftp           Succeeded
```

**Json conversion without between result**

```
> az container list -o json|convertfrom-json|select name,provisioningstate
```

**Output:**

```
 name provisioningstate
---- -----------------
```

I would expect the same result here as above.

why saving a temporary result brings different results than if the pipe commands are specified in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the runtime engine unrolls (or *enumerates*) all collection types when feeding output to a dowstream cmdlet

However, `ConvertFrom-Json` in PowerShell versions up to v6.x returns its results in a way that *prevents* the runtime from enumerating them - so the next cmdlet in the pipeline receives an `[object[]]` array as a single pipeline item.

You can solve this in a number of ways:

- Nest the initial pipeline:

```bsh
(az container list -o json |ConvertFrom-Json) |Select Name,ProvisioningState
```

- Let `ForEach-Object` unroll the array on return:

```bsh
az container list -o json |ConvertFrom-Json |ForEach { $_ } |Select Name,ProvisioningState
```

- Use an intermediate variable (as you've already found):

```bsh
$containers = az container list -o json |ConvertFrom-Json 
$containers |Select Name,ProvisioningState
```

- Upgrade to a newer version of PowerShell

  - The default behavior was changed in PowerShell [Core] 7.0

```bsh
if($PSVersionTable['PSVersion'].Major -ge 7){
  az container list -o json |ConvertFrom-Json |Select Name,ProvisioningState
}
```