# bash or powershell parsing jason file content

Tags: bash, powershell

I would like to manipulate the content of jason file.
I've tried with powershell or linux bash but I was unable to get what I want.
On linux, I was thinking to use jq tool, despite obtains data, I cannot manipulate them.

```
jq '.[].pathSpec, .[].scope' jasonfilepath
```

Current output:

```
"file"
"file"
"/u01/app/grid/*/bin/oracle"
"/u01/app/oracle/product/*/db_1/bin/oracle"
```

My goal is to obtain something similar as:

```
scope pathSpec
```

Like:

```
file /u01/app/grid/*/bin/oracle
file /u01/app/oracle/product/*/db_1/bin/oracle
```

Jason file sample

```
[
    {
        "actions": [
            "upload",
            "detect"
        ],
        "deep": false,
        "dfi": true,
        "dynamic": true,
        "inject": false,
        "monitor": false,
        "pathSpec": "/u01/app/grid/*/bin/oracle",
        "scope": "file"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            "upload",
            "detect"
        ],
        "deep": false,
        "dfi": true,
        "dynamic": true,
        "inject": false,
        "monitor": false,
        "pathSpec": "/u01/app/oracle/product/*/db_1/bin/oracle",
        "scope": "file"
    }
]
```

Do you have any idea to get this kind of expected output in **Powershell** and **bash**?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: Is this question about JSON (JavaScript Object Notation-encoded data) or Jason (a distinct superset of JSON specifically for serializing executable code)?

Comment: Assuming your JSON string is in a variable called `$json` in PowerShell you could do this: `$json | ConvertFrom-Json | %{"$($_.scope) $($_.pathSpec)"}`

Comment: Please don't ask two things in one question. Focus on one language (Powershell **or** bash). If you need it implemented in two languages (why?), try to translate it by yourself. If you get stuck, ask a **new** question.

Comment: In bash, try jq '.[].scope+ " " +.[].pathSpec' jasonfilepath

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a JSON input file named `file.json`:

In a **Linux / Bash environment**, use the following:

```
jq -r '.[] | .scope + " " + .pathSpec' file.json
```

---

In **PowerShell**, use the following (adapted from a comment by [JohnLBevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan)):

```
(Get-Content -Raw file.json | ConvertFrom-Json) | 
  ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.scope, $_.pathSpec }
```

Note the `(...)` around the pipeline with the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) call, which is necessary in *Windows PowerShell* (but no longer in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*) to ensure that the parsed JSON array is *enumerated* in the pipeline, i.e. to ensure that its elements are sent *one by one* - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61411805/45375) for more information.