# Iteration via PowerShell on the output of describe-instances json object + comparing the launch dates

Tags: json, powershell, loops, iterator

when I query describe-instances in the below way:

```
aws ec2 --profile $profile --region $region describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime,State]"
```

Output is showing in the below order:

```
[
    [
        [
            "i-0123456789",
            "2023-07-17T04:00:18+00:00",
            {
                "Code": 8,
                "Name": "running"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-9876543210",
            "2023-07-17T04:00:16+00:00",
            {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

with the help of iteration, I would like to see the output in the below format or any other way, so that for one value/item I would filter/iterate the other item

```
instanceid            launchdateb               code        Name       
i-0123456789       2023-07-17T04:00:18+00:00      8        running   
i-9876543210       2023-07-17T04:00:16+00:00     16        running
```

Have tried with for-each/foreach-object loop but it didn't work out, looking for your ideas/assistance on this.

and while doing the looping/iterating - how do I compare the Launchdate with any other date separately ?

Latest update of snippets, but not able to see the iterated values:

```
    $objects = aws ec2 --profile $profile --region $region describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime,State]" | Convertform-json 
  $objects | ForEach-Object {  
    # Construct and implicitly output a [pscustomobject]
    # instance from the elements of each nested array.
    $a = [pscustomobject] @{
      instanceid = $_[0][0]
      launchdateb = [datetimeoffset] $_[0][1]
      code = $_[0][2].Code
      name = $_[0][2].Name
      
   }
   Write-Output ("instanceid :"+$a.ToString())
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your update: `Convertform-json` -> `ConvertFrom-json`. The core problem is your attempt to use `.ToString()` on a `[pscustomobject]` instance, which - regrettably, due to a long-standing bug - yields the _empty string_ (see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163)). Replace `Write-Output ("instanceid:"+$a.ToString())` with `Write-Output "instanceid: $a"` or just `"instanceid : $a"` to fix this problem (that is, the bug doesn't surface in _string interpolation_).

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry Sir, I have rectified those errors and have tried in various way but still not able to get any value on **$a** , I have used **Write-Output ("instanceid :"+$a)** to check the vaule but this is showing blank

Comment: Does the self-contained sample code at the bottom of my answer not produce the expected output for you? If so, then the implication is that your real-life JSON input data doesn't have the structure that you think it does, which is an unrelated problem.

Comment: @mklement0 you helped on this a lot perhaps I'm still making some issue within this snippet which I'm not able to catch it, I will accept it as an Answer and will ask for the community for a reference on this since the output looks queit uniform in this case - something is going wrong from myside.
Thank you Sir, Really appreciate and admire your knowledge on it

Comment: My pleasure; I hope a follow-up question will solve the mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your fixed structure of nested JSON arrays, convert them to `[pscustomobject]` instances as follows:

```bash
# Note: Note how the whole ConvertFrom-Json call
#       must be enclosed in (...) in *Windows PowerShell*.
(ConvertFrom-Json (
  aws ec2 --profile $profile --region $region describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime,State]"
)) | 
  ForEach-Object {  
    # Construct and implicitly output a [pscustomobject]
    # instance from the elements of each nested array.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      instanceid = $_[0][0]
      launchdateb = [datetimeoffset] $_[0][1]
      code = $_[0][2].Code
      name = $_[0][2].Name
   }
}
```

Note:

- Enclosing the `ConvertFrom-Json` call as a whole in `(...)` ensures that the array resulting from the parsed JSON is *enumerated* in the pipeline, meaning that its *elements* are sent to `ForEach-Object`, *one by one*.
- This is only necessary in *Windows PowerShell*, where `ConvertFrom-Json` unexpectedly outputs arrays *as a whole*; this has been corrected in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), so you don't strictly need the `(...)` enclosure there - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412070/45375) for details.

The above directly outputs the resulting `[pscustomobject]` instances and produces display output similar to the one you request in the question; to capture these objects in a variable, as an array, prepend something like `$objects =`  to the entire command.

Note that casting the `.launchdateb` property values to `[datetimeoffset]` or `[datetime]` is only needed in *Windows PowerShell*; in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), JSON string property values containing ISO 8601 timestamp strings are *automatically* converted to - invariably *local* - `[datetime]` instances by [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json).

- The PowerShell 7+ behavior - up to at least v7.3.6 - is somewhat unfortunate, in that the automatic conversion to a local `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) involves the *loss of the specific UTC offset* (`+00:00` in your data) in the JSON data (which a subsequent `[datetimeoffset]` cannot recover).
- [GitHub issue #13598](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13598) is a proposal to add a `-DateKind` parameter to `ConvertFrom-Json`, which would enable `-DateKind Offset`, causing `[datetimeoffset]` ([`System.DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset)) instances that preserve the UTC offset to be returned. The proposal has been green-lit, but is yet to be implemented as of this writing.

Storing `[datetimeoffset]` / `[datetime]` instances in the `.launchdateb` properties should make it easy to perform date comparisons.

---

To spell out how to capture each `[pscustomobject]` in a variable and operate on it inside the `ForEach-Object` script block, providing the JSON input via a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings):

```bash
(@'
[
  [
      [
          "i-0123456789",
          "2023-07-17T04:00:18+00:00",
          {
              "Code": 8,
              "Name": "running"
          }
      ]
  ],
  [
      [
          "i-9876543210",
          "2023-07-17T04:00:16+00:00",
          {
              "Code": 16,
              "Name": "running"
          }
      ]
  ]
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json) |
  ForEach-Object {  
    $obj = 
      [pscustomobject] @{
        instanceid = $_[0][0]
        launchdateb = [datetimeoffset] $_[0][1]
        code = $_[0][2].Code
        name = $_[0][2].Name
      }
    # Output a string representation of the captured object.
    "Object: $obj"
}
```

The above yields (note the hashtable-*like* representation of `[pscustomobject]`s in the context of *string interpolation* (inside `"..."`, an [expandable (double-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings))):

```bash
Object: @{instanceid=i-0123456789; launchdateb=07/17/2023 04:00:18 +00:00; code=8; name=running}
Object: @{instanceid=i-9876543210; launchdateb=07/17/2023 04:00:16 +00:00; code=16; name=running}
```

Note:

- Do *not* use `"Object: " + $obj.ToString()` in lieu of `"Object: $obj"` above: due to a long-standing bug - see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163) - calling `.ToString()` on `[pscustomobject]` instances yields the *empty string*, up to at least PowerShell v7.3.6; by contrast, *string interpolation* (`"$obj"`) is *not* affected.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd suggest considering `[DateTimeOffset]` for the `launchdateb` type, it'll retain consisting string formatting with the input (still comparable to `[datetime]`) :)

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen. Please see my update: I've switched to `[datetimeoffset]`, but note that it wouldn't help in PS Core; the linked GitHub proposal may offer a solution in the future.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, what I meant to say is that a `[datetimeoffset]` cast doesn't help in PS Core with respect to the loss of the  _UTC-offset information_ - but it _is_ worth doing in WinPS. As for _string formatting_: the default stringification of a `[datetimeoffset]` instance doesn't use an ISO 8601 format and will therefore be somewhat different - though it _will_ show a UTC offset (which is probably what you meant); however, in PS Core, the to-local conversion means that, unless the caller happens to be in the same time zone, the stringification will show a _different_ UTC offset.

Comment: @mklement0 sorry for asking this, Sir would you let me know that how should I get output of each object ? I am using $Value = Your_Answer, then dong $Value.instanceid but not getting anything ?

And how do I construct and implicitly output a [pscustomobject] if you kindly give an example to elaborate this part please

Comment: @MoneyTimes, the command already constructs and implicitly outputs the `[pscustomobject]` instances, so there's nothing else to do but to _capture_ the output objects, which `$value = ConvertFrom-Json ...` should indeed do, and `$value.instanceId` should then list _all_ instance IDs. If, by contrast, you want to store _each_ `[pscustomobject]` instance in a variable, so as to work with it _inside the `ForEach-Object` script block_, use `$value = [pscustomobject] @{ ... }`

Comment: @mklement0 I am doing this but not getting value sofar :( 

  ForEach-Object {  
    # Construct and implicitly output a [pscustomobject]
    # instance from the elements of each nested array.
    $a = [pscustomobject] @{
      instanceid = $_[0][0]
      launchdateb = [datetimeoffset] $_[0][1]
      code = $_[0][2].Code
      name = $_[0][2].Name
      
   }
   Write-Output ("value "+$a)
} 

Am I missing anything here ? or am I  correctly using write-out

Comment: @MoneyTimes, the lack of line breaks in comments and the limited formatting makes code hard to read. If the problem is that the property _values_ of the object stored in `$a` are blank, the implication is that the actual JSON your `aws` command returns differs from the sample JSON shown in your question. Also, just to rule out an obvious problem: Your `ForEach-Object` call must be directly preceded by  `ConvertFrom-Json (
  aws ec2 --profile $profile --region $region describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime,State]"
) |`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if you kindly post that how do I see the output of each object separately by Write-object, that would be great

Comment: @MoneyTimes I'm not quite sure what you mean. You can assign the output from the pipeline suggested in the answer: `[array]$results = ConvertFrom-Json ...` and then inspect each item in the resulting array individually: eg. `$results[0]` for the first object

Comment: @MoneyTimes, I forgot to consider that you may be running _Windows PowerShell_ rather than [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). If so, you need to enclose the entire `ConvertFrom-Json` call in `(...)` - please see my update for details; I've also added a bottom section that spells out a full example with your sample JSON data.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes I have used part which I have updated in the answer but somehow the iterated values are not parsing through object, perhaps I made some misses here !!? trying to figure it out
Note able to fetch out any value while doing **$a.**

Comment: @mklement0 once you are available, could you take a look the part I updated with your answer in my question below plz ? just would like to see if it's working on powershell ise

Comment: @MoneyTimes, I've already left a comment directly on your question to explain the problem with the snippet currently at the bottom of your question. As an aside, regarding use of the Windows PowerShell ISE, I suggest avoiding it and migrating to Visual Studio Code - see the next comment.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if you have sometime to look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497402/to-get-the-instance-count-of-a-certain-period-via-launchtime-wrt-powershell