# to get the instance count of a certain period via LaunchTime wrt Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, date-format, date-formatting

I have tried with the below

Is my Date format correct as per awscli LaunchTime ?

**To get the last 5 Days Instance count which was created via LaunchTime with of AWS cli in Powershell**:

```
    $getDays = Get-Date
    $5Days = $getDays.AddDays(-5).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    $instancesCreated = aws ec2 --profile $awsProfile --region $awsRegion describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime>='$5Days']"
    Write-Output (" Total instances count in last 5days : " +$instancesCreated)
```

But I am not getting the actual count here, getting the Total counts - anything if I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- I do not have access to AWS, so the following is untested.
- I'm assuming that the `Reservations[*].Instances[*]` part of your query is correct.

Assuming that you're looking to extract just the `.InstanceId` property values of the matching instances, using a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query, as supported by the `aws` CLI's [`--query` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side):

Replace:

```bash
--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime>='$5Days']"
```

with:

```bash
--query "(Reservations[*].Instances[])[?LaunchTime>='$5Days'].InstanceId"
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your observations again @mklement0 !! 

But here is two things happening as I changed with the replaced query <a> now it's not showing any result(but earlier it was fetching the whole instance's record) <b>when I was modifying with *.AddDays* and then I checked with the dataType of the modified date - it is showing me String type but if I check the describe-instance api it says the datatype of date is ISO 8601 [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html] - Am I missing anything while converting the launchDate(launch-time) ?

Comment: @MoneyTimes, see if my update helps. Yes, the date _format_ is ISO 8601, but dates are represented as _strings_ in JSON. This format that ensures that lexical sorting is equivalent to chronological sorting.